# Linux reboot the terminal for npm command function

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, sh

I have a shell script where I am installing the `npm` using `nvm`. Since after my installation of `nvm`, it installs the `npm` using `nvm install node -> nvm use <version>`.

After this, I have `npm cache clean`, which cannot recognize the command `npm`. **Since I know that, for getting the node to work in the terminal, we need to restart**. But I have upcoming commands in the shell for which bash cannot stop, hence I get errors, because I am using `npm` to install other software tools.

Error is: `npm command is not found`.

**Shell Script**

```
# This is for the running the project
#!/bin/bash

# Install NodeJS using nvm
nvm install node
nvm install 11.12.0
nvm use 11.12.0

# Install Cordova and Ionic
npm cache clean
sudo npm install -g cordova@8.1.2 ionic
```

Is there anyway that I can continue the process without restarting terminal for command process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try call `npm` with help `nvm exec npm`

```
nvm exec cache clean
nvm exec npm install -g cordova@8.1.2 ionic
```

Don't use `sudo` in script. Run your script with needed for running rights. Or run shell script with help `sudo`

Comment: Hey what happens if I have multiple `sudo` scripts in my shell script file?

Comment: Nothing. The script is executed. But following the principle of least privilege, run as little as you can as root. Therefore, `sudo` from within the your script.

Comment: It worked **pvlt**. Thanks for the help. Marking it as correct